# Jboss 5.1, hibernate, using Oracle8gDialect when i'm specifying Oracle10gDialect

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jboss

I've inherited an app that i'm trying to get running locally on jboss 5.1. The app is using hibernate and we're using Oracle 11g for our database.

When i start the app i get this error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Problem while trying to load or access OracleTypes.CURSOR value
```

and this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect can not access a member of class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes with modifiers ""
```

In my persistence.xml file i'm setting this:

```
<persistence-unit name="DomainPU">
    <jta-data-source>java:/AuthorizationDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Any advise on what is causing these errors and how to fix them? I'm not even sure what to try at this point.

Comment: What version of the Oracle driver are you using? Be sure you're not using an old or deprecated version.

Comment: I've not faced this error, but it looks like a problem with the oracle jdbc driver version. Have you tried with ojdbc14 (for Oracle 10g: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html). Take a look at this post as well: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3190796

Comment: Isn't ojdbc14 for java 4? I'm compiling in java 6.

Comment: The ojdbc14 driver is for java 4 or 5, to access Oracle10g DBs, but it should also work fine in Java6. On the other hand the ojdbc6 driver is for Oracle11g, as far as I know you should be able to access Oracle10g with this driver, but the problem you're experiencing makes me doubt it. (The configuration we use at work is Java 6.x + JBoss 5.1 + ojdbc14 driver + Oracle10g).

Comment: I actually just checked what db we are using and we're using 11g. But we use the 10g dialect apparently. So that means that ojdbc14 will not work correct?

Comment: Ah, ok! I though you were using an Oracle 10g DB, ojdbc14 is a Oracle 10g driver, which is backwards compatible, but not forward compatible, so no, you can't use it (or at least it can't be waranteed that it will work properly). But why are you using the 10g dialect if the DB is 11g?

Comment: I don't know. That's what we use in some other apps and that's what i was told to use. It works in all our other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a version of jboss in the SVN repo and from what i can tell, it looks like it may have an upgraded version of hibernate with it.